# How to pass delegates and "normal type" arguments in a function

Tags: c#

I will explain my problem directly with code. Initially, I had the code below:

```
class Program
{
   private static Obj A = new Obj(...);

   private static void Function(Func<object[]> m)
   {
      object[] result = m();
      ...
   }

   static void main()
   {
      double a,b,c = 0;
      string d = " ";
      Function(() => A.MethodX(a,b,c));
      Function(() => A.MethodY(d,a,b));
      ...
   }
}
```

This allows me to use a same function in which I can use any methods of my object. Now, what I'm asking for is: is it possible to have another argument in this function so it will be like:

```
class Program
{
   private static Obj A = new Obj(...);

   private static void Function(List<string> b, Func<object[]> m)
   {
      object[] result = m();
      ...uses my other argument
   }

   static void main()
   {
      List<string> x = new List<string>();
      double a,b,c = 0;
      string d = " ";
      //Function(() => A.MethodX(a,b,c)); -> How to give my List named "x" to the Function ?
      ...
   }
}
```

And if yes, how can I implement it ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple; pass `x` as the first argument:

```
static void main()
{
    List<string> x = new List<string>();
    double a,b,c = 0;
    string d = " ";
    Function(x, () => A.MethodX(a,b,c)); 
}
```

Comment: @user234461 Because `a` and `b` are unassigned? Code has clearly been omitted for brevity.